# how to change the postion of the enter button to the centre of the page?

Tags: html, css

How to get the button from the top corner to the centre of the page

```css
.button {
  background-color: rgb(168, 229, 70);
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 3px solid yellow;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<a href="">
  <div class="button">enter</div>
</a>
<!--insert a link that take to a page that has info about the developers
    -->
```

i have no idea what to try?

Comment: Why do you have an empty anchor around your button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can add this :

```
 .button{
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  }
```

but you should replace the (( class =" button "  )) to the  **a** not the **div** like this :

```
  <a class ="button" href="">
    <div> enter </div>
  </a>
```

to make the button be clicked if you click on it only .. but if you write the class button in the div this will make the button be clicked if you click any where next to it

Answer (score 1):

adding this should do the trick

```
    .button {
      display: block;
      margin: auto; }
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the white space to the left and right side of the button will be clickable

Comment: @j08691 dammit i didn't even notice that, thanks

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

This will make your button come into the center of the page.

```css
.center{
  height : 100vh;
  width : 100vw;
  display : grid;
  align-items : center;
  justify-content : center;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
<button><a href="https://stackoverflow.com">Hi There</a></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add this:

```
.button {
    margin: auto;
}
```

or this :

```
.button {
    margin-left:25%;
    margin-right:25%;
}
```

Comment: As the other answer before yours that suggested essentially the same thing, the problem with this is that the white space to the left and right side of the button will be clickable

Answer (score 0):

```css
.button {
  background-color: rgb(168, 229, 70);
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 3px solid yellow;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  position:fixed;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%)
}
```

```html
<a href="">
  <div class="button">enter</div>
</a>
<!--insert a link that take to a page that has info about the developers
    -->
```

Comment: Please don't just dump code and expect everyone to understand what it was that you did. Explain your answer fully.

Comment: I just add 4 lines on his code... it's quite understandable, I don't think it needs a LOT of explanation.

Comment: I didn't say it needed "a LOT" of explanation, but it sure needed some...

Comment: so... sorry for my english...fixed position would position your element as "fix", you could use also absolute if you put it in body, it'll be absolute of body (screen). after you put it at 50% left and top. Origin of element itself is top left, so you put a translate -50% -50% on it and it's positioned exactly in middle